# Measuring speed of a Tween object

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, gsap

I have tweened an object (its x property) with tweenlite, and I want to measure the instantaneous speed during the tween, at a given moment.

I know I could make an array that constantly records recent x values at onUpdate, and then take the difference. But are there more efficient ways of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't understand why you need the speed, but, it's simple math. You already know the distance the object will travel and the time it needs to arrive on destination. So,

speedTimeUnit = distanceTraveled/timeNeededToArrive;

or if you need to know speed in frames

speedFramesUnit = distanceTraveled/(timeNeededToArrive*frameRate);

Of course, this is in case that time is in seconds ...

Comment: This of course assumes the tween is linear — which isn't often the case.

Comment: Ah, thanks Rizzla.
I am developing a brick breaker game, and I needed speed so that I could alter the speed of the ball in proportion to the speed of the pad.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't another way to measure it.

Anyway you need to know the distance between two points and moving time, and if you have animation in timeline the only way to know these params it to measure it. If your tween is linear, you can store the initial position and timestamp and at any moment the instantaneous speed will be:

```
    var origPos:Point = new Point(obj.x, obj.y);
    var origTimestamp:Number = getTimer();
    var currentPos:Point = new Point();

    currentPos.x = obj.x;
    currentPos.y = obj.y;
    var speed:Number = currentPos.subtract(origPos).length/(getTimer() - origTimestamp);
```

If you don't sure whether tween leaner or not replace `origPos` and `origTimestamp` after each measurement.